# correlations between columns of samples in R

Tags: r

I am working on some analysis work and after running softwares between same samples i got output like this

```
>software1
>id sample1 sample2
 a  0           0
 b  0           0
 c  0           0
 d  0           0
 e  0           0
 f  0           0
 g  0.518775    0.549079
 h  0.0233247   0.101596
 i  15.8679     15.45


>software2
>id sample1 sample2
 a     0    0
 b     0    0
 c     0    0
 d     0    0
 e     0    0
 f     0    0
 g    18.6225669551756  23.7346441585572
 h   199.37101093188    157.926670747323
 i    10.9544511501033  3.65148371670111
```

now i want to compare or correlate samples between different softwares used...like between sample1 from software1 and sample1 from software2 and 
sample2 from software1 and sample2 from software2

i am new to R and learning it and any help would be great?

i calculated the correlation between samples now using cor function.can i develop heatmap between them?

Comment: Google "R correlation" https://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=Zwt13C0m1D7WYpW4vwp9Cw&cp=5&gs_id=i&xhr=t&q=r+correlation&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=r+cor&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.dGI&fp=f65a83316a576e4a&biw=1920&bih=979 Sorry, mate, but this is really such a basic question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cor(software1[c("sample1", "sample2")],
    software2[c("sample1", "sample2")])

#             sample1    sample2
# sample1 -0.08296432 -0.1202152
# sample2 -0.07804807 -0.1151872
```

I will note that the number of zeros in those examples raise the question of whether a different summary method than correlation might  be more desirable. Pearson correlation assumes the two vectors would be drawn from a continuous distribution with a low probability of duplicates.

Comment: I calculated the correlation between samples using cor function.can i develop heatmap between the samples? @DWin

Comment: No. For a heatmap you need three values: x, y, and a "heat"-matrix.

Comment: @Dwin, see the edit I made to your answer (you missed the fact the OP was asking for a correlation matrix). Now it does provide everything needed for a heat map.

Comment: @flodel: I think you deserve the check.